# Email - Marketing quebra de coluna em mobile

Tags: css, html5, table

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um site para um email marketing, ele esta pronto, mas andei olhando na internet e vi que da para deixar responsivo sem usar media query... e tentei fazerm alguns sites explica, mas não consegui entender direito mas consegui desenvolver, a diferença é que não esta funcionando... tenho um `td` com duas colunas e queria quebrar elas... deixar uma embaixo da outra quando for mobile... passar de `480px` ele já quebra. Mas não esta funcionando...

eu quero que essa parte que quebra em dois... fique um embaixo do outro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o codigo abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; font-size: 14px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; text-align: center; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; width: 100% !important;">
    <center style="-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; width: 100%;">
        <div style="max-width: 600px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-align: left; width: 94%;" align="left">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
            <tr height="90">
                <td bgcolor="#fff" width="0%" height="0%"></td>
                <td bgcolor="#fff" border="0" height="100%" valign="middle" align="left">
                    <a href="#" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                        <img src="https://i2.wp.com/veropublic.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/apple-iphone6-email-marketing.jpg?resize=780%2C873" alt="Verollate" width="100%" height="auto" border="0" style="color: #000;"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#fff" width="0%" height="0%"></td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#000" width="0%" height="0%"></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000" width="100%" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; max-width: 552px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="carrinho" bgcolor="#000" style="border-color: #000; width: 34%; border-width: 25px 10px 25px; vertical-align: top; height: auto; border-style: solid; color: #000; font-size: 14px; text-align: left; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" align="left">
                                <img src="https://i2.wp.com/veropublic.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/apple-iphone6-email-marketing.jpg?resize=780%2C873" alt="Carrinho verollate" width="100%" border="0"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td id="conteudo-1" bgcolor="#000" style="border-color: #000; width: 66%; border-width: 10px 10px 20px; border-style: solid; color: #fff; font-size: 14px; text-align: left; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; vertical-align: center;" align="left">
                                  Tenho o prazer de lhe apresentar a <b>Vero Latte</b>, uma nova experiência de gelato, elegante no tamanho e no modo de servir.
                  Quando a criei, em 2014, foi pensando justamente em momentos únicos da vida. E a celebração de um casamento é um desses momentos.
                  <br><br>
                  Cada receita e desenvolvida por mim com paixão e exclusividade, por meio da utilizção de nobres ingredientes em uma produção
                  legitimamente artesanal. Será muito especial ter a oportunidade de apresentar nossa marca a você.
                  <br><br>
                  Então, eu gostaria de convidá-la para conhecer o showroom da Vero Latte e participar de uma deliciosa tarde de degustação em nosso espaço.

                  <br><br>
                  Aguardo sua presença,
                  <br>
                  Mariana Galvão
                  <br>
                  (11)2506-9295
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
        <td bgcolor="#000" width="0%" height="0%"></td>
                <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <td colspan="3" align="center">
                        <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/fita-vermelha-33946534.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, fico feliz, obrigado....

Comment: Nathan, por qual motivo não quer usar media query? É impossível adicionar pelo menos um bootstrap nesse projeto? usar table para determinar a disposição dos objetos não é uma boa prática...

Comment: Então, pois email-marketing ele não lê essas coisas, por exemplo gmail ele não lê media query, já o inbox nativo do ios já consegu, são praticas que estragam a estrutura de um email-marketing... fiquei sabendo dessas coisas nesse link - http://sergiolopes.org/email-newsletter-mobile-responsivo/ ... também nesse link - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ ... fica a dica pra quem quiser...

Comment: Intendi, mas dá uma olhada aqui na doc do gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css ai diz que ele suporta as media queries, o primeiro link que vc mandou está com data de 2012, pode ser que de lá pra cá eles tenham adicionado essa funcionalidade.

Comment: opa, obrigado... vou dar uma olhada sim

Comment: Só vai conseguir isto se trocar as colunas por outro tipo de elemento e usar `float`, é provavel que media-query funcione na maioria das situações, mas não tem como quebrar `<td>` por que a estrutura de tabelas é totalmente diferente de float e inline-block.